# PHP - String does not get identified as date

Tags: php, validation, date

Hi I have a function that checks to see if a user input string is a valid date. The user has to input the date in the format `25-January-2018` and it checks to see if it can be converted to the format `25-01-2018`. However when I test the function using a date where both the month and day are single digits then it returns false even though a valid date has been entered.

```
function validateDate($date){
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-F-Y', $date);
    return $d && $d->format('j-F-Y') === $date;
}

echo validateDate("03-February-2018"); //Returns false when it should be true
```

Comment: `j-F-Y` !== `d-F-Y`.... `return $d && $d->format('j-F-Y') === ltrim($date, '0');`

Comment: Manual:http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#format

Answer (score 3):

You should replace the `j-F-Y` with `d-F-Y`.

`j` means 1 to 31 while `d` means 01 to 31 then your two formats are different for the given date.

The following code works:

```
function validateDate($date){
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-F-Y', $date);
    return $d && $d->format('d-F-Y') === $date;
}

var_dump(validateDate("03-February-2018"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function could work :

```
   return $d && $d->format('d-F-Y') === $date;
```

but if your want to check if it's a valid date use this :

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('d-F-Y', "03-February") // returns false if not a valid date & Object if valid
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime()` function better.

```
function validateDate($date){
   $timestamp = strtotime($date);
   $newDate = date('d-F-Y', $timestamp); 
   return ($timestamp && $newDate);
}

echo validateDate("03-February-2018");
```